# Custom button background [ANDROID]

Tags: android, xamarin, button

I want to make this kind of button in xamarin android app:

[image: buttonexample]

How to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` can be used to achieve a similar result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cross_square"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/myText"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank u :) It is possible to use this as a control, in separate file? For make this reusable and change image and text only?

Comment: Yes you can . you can  put it in seperate file and use  it by  `<include layout="@layout/myButton"/>` , but you will have to change the the image and text programatically

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e3ff0000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_message"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#95ff0000"
        android:text="Nilesh" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply use `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"` in Button of your Lay out xml.

Or

If you want use an image for Button background.
The you can use `android:background="@drawable/your_btn_image"`.
in this case you just want to copy the image in to the drawable folder of your project.